# Javascript Changing Sentence by Time

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I would like to submit 1 script that is being explore. I would like to make my web notification by changing offer 1 to offer 2 and then 3 on the website every 30 sec.

```js
<script>
      setInterval(function(){ $(".custom").stop().slideToggle('fast'); }, 2000);
      $(".custom-close").click(function() {
        $(".custom").stop().slideToggle('fast');
      });
</script>
```

```html
<section class="custom">
    <div>Offer 1<br>50%<b></b> Product Name
    <small>In 1 hour only</small>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-close"></div>
     <div>Offer 2<br>30%<b></b> Product Name
    <small>In 2 hour only</small>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-close"></div>
     <div>Offer 3<br>10%<b></b> Product Name
    <small>In 3 hour only</small>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-close"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest for you to use Bootstrap's "Carousel", you can even define the desired interval, which in your case is every 30 seconds.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 30000
})
```

Get it here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/